# Going to first Screen of Navigation controller in iPad

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I am stucked at a point in NavigationController..

I am in the third screen of navigation Controller. When I press Home placed on my third screen, I want to go to the first screen of my NavigationController.

Please, can anybody guide me how to do it?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use popToRootViewController method of navigationController. Below is code snippet:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this solves your problem.